# How to create null output effect?

Tags: sox, libsox

I want to write a program just don't produce output file. How can I do that?
I try to create `sox_format_t` with empty string or NULL string:

```
sox_format_t* out = sox_open_write(NULL, &signalInfo, &encodingInfo, NULL, NULL, NULL);
sox_format_t* out = sox_open_write("", &signalInfo, &encodingInfo, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I try to pass 0 args to output effect:

```
sox_effect_options(outputEffect, 0, args);
```

None of them work.

Comment: If you don't want libsox to produce a file, then what is the purpose of using libsox? Please explain what problem you are trying to solve with your program.

Comment: well, i am trying to create noise profile. therefore producing output file is not what i want. input --> trim --> noiseprof --> output. that's the chain i trying to use. i somehow manage to create null output. but i got error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try this code and it worked

```
sox_format_t* out = sox_open_write("", &signalInfo, &encodingInfo, "null", NULL, NULL);
```

but combine with 'trim' and 'noiseprof', my program print error message with no noise profile file.

Comment: Good catch, libsox supports a special filetype ["null"](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/code/ci/master/tree/src/nulfile.c) to discard the output. As for the error, maybe it helps to specify a (valid) file path anyway. If your OS supports it, you could try ["/dev/null"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device).

Comment: i found out why, my bad programming. i pass wrong argument. after i fix it, it print 'Premature EOF' and create file i want.